# How to use nginx on Docker for Windows as reverse proxy for localhost?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker for Windows and want to set up nginx as reverse proxy. All is working fine but if I want to define a proxy to my localhost I always get a 502 or 504 error. I thought setting an `extra_host` would solve my problem but didn't. Is there any other IP that I can try to set as host or is something else wrong?
**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  etc:
      driver: local

services:
  nginx:
      container_name: nginx
      image: nginx:latest
      volumes:
        - ./etc:/etc/nginx
      ports:
        - 8088:80
      extra_hosts:
        - localhost:127.0.0.1
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

events { 
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /auth {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/auth;
    }

    location /graphql {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/graphql;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

    }

    location ^~ / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/auth;
    }

    location /sso/login {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/auth;
    }

  }

}
```

**PS:** all referred paths are docker-containers e.g. `/auth` is a keycloak authentification server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem myself. If you open the docker settings (right-click on docker icon) then you have the following network settings. 
[image]
Per default the DNS server is set to automatic -> change this to **fixed 8.8.8.8**
Then you can access your containers with **10.0.75.2** instead localhost.
Last but not least add this address as `extra_host` to your docker-compose file and fire it up.

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  etc:
      driver: local

services:
  nginx:
      container_name: nginx
      image: nginx:latest
      volumes:
        - ./etc:/etc/nginx
      ports:
        - 8088:80
      extra_hosts:
        - localhost:10.0.75.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation,](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/) with docker for mac we can use `host.docker.internal` to resolve the internal IP used by the host

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass   http://host.docker.internal:8080;
}
```